# acer Aspire R5-471T issue when waking

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, acer-aspire, intel-graphics

I was recommended to uninstall and reinstall my Graphics driver from my computer about two weeks ago, and now every time I shut my laptop closed and it goes to sleep, upon opening it, the screen has all these colorful lines on it on a solid gray background.

To fix it, I simply tap the power button once, and the computer goes to sleep once more, and I wait about 20 seconds for one of the indicator lights to shut off, and I then tap the power button again, and the Acer logo pops up and my computer begins to work normally, prompting me to login.

I have absolutely no idea how to fix this and was hoping someone had advice. Thank you!

http://community.acer.com/t5/Swift-Spin-S-and-R-Series/Sleep-Mode-causes-weird-screen-issues-not-black-screen-on-Acer/m-p/525956#M8353

This post describes the same issue I have, and no one is able to solve it! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same problem with  my Aspire R14 and I seem to have fixed it (at least for now).  In "Settings" go to "Troubleshoot" and select "Windows Update".  Run the troubleshooter (as an admin) and it fixed some issues automatically with the registry.  Hope this works for you too!

Comment: Thanks, Joey! There is also a relatively simple workaround (not a true fix) whereby you bypass the sleep option and have your computer go straight to hibernate when the laptop screen is closed. Doing so will bypass the issue which only occurred for me when my computer was in Sleep Mode! Thank you for the answer though, and so I will try yours now!